# n-th derivative where $n$ is a real number?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, fractional-calculus

We know that 
$$\frac{d^n}{dt^n} e^{at}= a^n e^{at}; \, n\in \mathbb N.$$
I want to know if the result is true if $n$ is a real number, i.e., $n\in \mathbb R$ ?

Comment: Something to look up: fractional calculus

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's one possible definition. You know the result holds true for any non-negative integer $n$, so you define it to be $a^ne^{at}$ for fractional $n$. As others have pointed out this is one of the starting points of fractional calculus.

Answer (score 2):

One common definition of the fractional derivative is $D^\alpha$ of $f(x) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(m-\alpha)} \frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x \frac{f(t)}{(x-t)^\alpha} dt$  (for any $0<\alpha<1)$ 
Substituting in $\alpha = n$ and $f(x) = e^{ax}$ we get
$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(1-n)} \frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x \frac{e^{ax}}{(x-t)^n} dt$$
$$=\frac{e^{ax}x^{-n}(n-ax-1)}{(n-1)\Gamma(1-n)}$$
If we set $n=\frac{1}{2}$ we get the half-derivative as
$$=\frac{2e^{ax}x^{-1/2}(ax+\frac{1}{2})}{\sqrt{\pi}}$$
While this may be strange, it may be somewhat comforting to note that the limit as $n \to 1$ in the above formula yields the answer $ae^{ax}$ as expected. Now, this isn't the only the only fractional derivative out there, and you could very well choose to simply *define* your answer as correct!

**Note:**
In general, the derivative formula  I am using is as follows: for any $m-1<\alpha<m$ where $m \in \mathbb{N}$, $\frac{1}{\Gamma(m-\alpha)} \frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x \frac{f(t)}{(x-t)^{\alpha+1-m}} dt$
This is sometimes known as the Left-Hand Definition, and a derivation can be found [here](http://www3.nd.edu/~msen/Teaching/UnderRes/FracCalc.pdf)

**Note 2**: I have provided a comparison of the two derivatives, your's in orange and mine in red. The function $ae^{ax}$ is provided in blue to show the convergence of the the two derivatives as $n \to 1$:
[image: Function Comparisons]

Comment: How I would like to know how these drawings moving! They are beautiful and a kind of mathematical hymn to technology (besides certainly be a means of knowledge).

Comment: @Piquito For the actual graphing and movement I used the free online graphing calculator Desmos - you can find the link to my graph [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fj5kbg8j7w). As for the GIF animation, I used the website [GIFsmos](http://www.gifsmos.com/), which uses GifShot available free online from Yahoo! to record Desmos graphs while parameters are changing... In fact, since GIFsmos uses the full Desmos API, you can even create graphs through the site itself (although I prefer to use the full-screen interface on Desmos.com)

Comment: @Piquito I wholeheartedly agree with you on your observations! The union of Algebra and Geometry does often seem like a "hymn", especially when it comes to concepts such as Fractional Calculus... I've always felt the best way to understand the field of analysis is through visual aids, as otherwise the beauty in the smooth transitions between derivatives is lost. Of course, in this case I would argue the OP's definition is "smoother", though the OP's definition is specific to this specific instance