# Problems Calculating Fractional Derivative

Tags: proof-verification, exponential-function, fractional-calculus

I have been trying to calculate the fractional derivative of $e^{ax}$ using the Liouville Left-Sided derivative, which states that, for $x>0$ and $0<n<1$, $D^n f(x) = \frac{1}{1-n} \frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x \frac{f(t)}{(x-t)^n}dt$
However, I have been quite unsuccessful. Using the standard Liouville Derivative (i.e. $D^n f(x) = \frac{1}{1-n} \frac{d}{dx} \int_{-\infty}^x \frac{f(t)}{(x-t)^n}dt$ for all real $x$ and $0<n<1$) Mathematica gets the answer $D^n e^{ax} = a^n e^{ax}$ as expected. However, when I run the same Left-Handed derivative through Mathematica I get the following
$$\frac{e^{ax}x^{-n}}{\Gamma(1-n)}\left[ax\operatorname{E}_{n-1}(ax) + (n-ax-1)\operatorname{E}_n(ax) + (ax)^n\Gamma(-n)\right]$$
Using the identity $\operatorname{E_n(ax)} = ax^{n-1}\Gamma(1-n,ax)$ on both of the exponential integrals gave the following result:
$$\frac{e^{ax}x^{-n}}{\Gamma(1-n)}\left[a^2x^{n-1}\Gamma(2-n,ax) + (anx^{n-1}-a^2x^n-ax^{n-1})\Gamma(1-n,ax) + (ax)^n\Gamma(1-n)\right]$$

Regardless, the above expressions do not seem to match $e^{ax}a^n$ numerically, so I fear I have either made a mistake here or the two chosen Liouville derivatives do not match up (which I doubt)

**Note:** that this is purely recreational - this is not for anything other than gaining experience working with the methods of fractional calculus. More specifically, I was attempting to answer the question found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1792289/n-th-derivative-where-n-is-a-real-number) graphically, but got stuck while experimenting with the Left-Handed Derivative. Also, I am using the definitions found [here](http://www.hindawi.com/journals/mpe/2014/238459/) (with some minor variable substitution of course)

**Edit:** As noted in the tags, I am specifically looking for a proof verification, not alternate proof techniques (although alternate techniques are nevertheless appreciated!)

Comment: Typo: Liouville?

Comment: @SimpleArt Yep, edited - that's why you don't let spell check run on Mathematicians' names XD

Comment: Don't even get me started on the pronunciations..

Comment: you didn't write what is your definition of the fractional derivative !

Comment: @user1952009 He said he was using Liouville's Left-Sided derivative, which can be found 1) in the link and 2) at the top of the post.

Comment: @SimpleArt thanks.  I go to all the trouble to state my definition in two ways and I still get people asking for it XD

Comment: @SimpleArt : I know some definitions of the fractional derivative, I'm asking him (and you) to write one of those !!! (it seems obvious that you'll need it for proving that $D^s e^{ax} = a^s e^{ax}$)

Comment: @user1952009 hence why I already defined it... read line 1 of my post. I quote: "I have been trying to [use] the Liouville Left-Sided derivative, which states that, for $x>0$ and $0<n<1$, $D^n f(x) = \frac{1}{1-n} \frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x \frac{f(t)}{(x-t)^n}dt$" I already well defined within my post what definition I am using... there is no need to respecify this

Comment: Try the following read for a good breakdown of fractional calculus and strange discrepancies: http://www.xuru.org/fc/Intro.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is no "standard" fractional derivative.

The **Riemann-Liouville** derivative 
$$
D^{\alpha}_a f(x) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(1-\alpha )} \frac{d}{dx} \int\limits_a^x \frac{f(t)}{(x-t)^\alpha}dt
$$
indeed has a different integration range than the **Liouville** derivative 
$$
\mathcal{D}^{\alpha}  f(x) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(1-\alpha )} \frac{d}{dx} \int\limits_{-\infty}^x \frac{f(t)}{(x-t)^\alpha}dt
$$
The terminology can be confusing for a newcomer to the field.

The exponent function in particular behaves in a different manner.
See for example this reference as a starting point:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236221379_Fractional_Calculus_A_survey_of_useful_formulas

Comment: Hmm...  Looks promising. Thanks for checking out my answer so long after posting! I'll read more into the links you have. Specifics I have are why both integrals converged if the integration ranges differ... I would think that would imply overlap in integration ranges,  but I could easily be wrong. From that,  I hope to learn under what conditions the integrals are equal and under which they are unequal.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\frac d{dx}e^{ax}=ae^{ax}$$

We also have that, for $n\in\mathbb N$

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{ax}=a^ne^{ax}$$

or, one could assume that this works for $n\in\mathbb R$, and put into notations,

$$D^ne^{ax}=a^ne^{ax}$$

This is the result we want to get, probably through the methods you are given.

I will say the above result should be correct via induction

$$D^{n-1}\frac d{dx}e^{ax}=aD^{n-1}e^{ax}=a^ne^{ax}=D^ne^{ax}$$

In my experience (not much) I will say that induction is the easiest way to go about this.

We also find that this formula should hold for more than $n\in\mathbb N$

$$D^kD^ne^{ax}=D^{k+n}e^{ax}$$

From that, we can show that it holds for $n\in\mathbb Q$

To show that it holds for $n\in\mathbb R$, assume that it is continuous.

Comment: Hmmm.. an interesting proof. Thank you, I hadn't considered such an elementary proof using induction. A beautiful argument here! Nevertheless, I am more concerned about finding the error in my argument (hence the "Proof Verification" tag). As such, I won't accept this answer as is. Nevertheless, thank you very much - I'd say you have more experience (or at least ingenuity) than you seem to believe!

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen No problem.  Sometimes the formulas for fractional calculus just aren't worth using.  Feel free to use this answer if you want.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Well, if $D^ne^{ax}=a^ne^{ax}$ is obvious, then induction should do it.

Comment: This approach resembles the approach of Euler and Leibniz. Modern theory is more subtle.

Comment: @user48672 I just thought it was the easiest approach for this problem.